# How to put modal in react-navgation root?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jsx, react-navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kQnk.png)

Like the above pic shows, i want to put a  modal in my root  app, then i can control the modal show anytime anywhere i want, but the problems is where the modalClass should place in 。

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is the problem? Please show some research effort

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature introduced in React 16 called `Portals` designed to handle exactly such cases.

You add one more entry (modal-root) in your `index.html` file like so

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app-root"></div>
    <div id="modal-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then render into the modal DOM element

```
render() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    this.props.children,
    document.getElementById("modal-root"),
  );
}
```

For the reference Portals [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)